# how to run external program inside a monkeyrunner code?

Tags: android, centos, jython, monkeyrunner

I have a monkeyrunner code (file extension is .py) which is working fine. I am using CentOS. Now, I need to run a  an external program and I need to insert that code in the monkeyrunner code. how do I do it? What do I need to import and what is the command?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module.

Answer (score 0):

```
import subprocess
# Your code ...  

# Call the external program/ script:
subprocess.call('your script', shell = True)
```